# GeoWebCache: Missing tiles after reseed

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

Using geoserver 2.9.2. I'm generating vector-tiles (geojson output, EPSG:27700) for the full extent of a layer, for only one zoom level. Estimated number of tiles is around 17.000.000. After full generation, when I can see that each job has completed, let's say, 2125000 tiles, on disk I have only around 1.000.000 files.

the disk quota is set at 10 GiB, and the total size of tiles cache is 4.5 GiB.

I tried to use only one thread... same result: the tiles completed displayed by GWC interface is different by the number of files on disk.

In OL, when I hit the missing tile, and on the request header I can see the MISS, on disk, the missing file is generated.

The geoserver is running in a docker container, with cachedir mapped on a NAS.
(I tried also on a fresh installed geoserver (not using a docker container)

Somebody know what is with this difference between GWC completed tiles and actual files on disk?

note1:
if for a given extent is generating 16 PNG files, for the same extent is generating only 1 geojson file.

The ratio between PNG generated files and GEOJSON generated files is 16:1,
which makes sense: for ~17.000.000 estimated tiles to generate ~1.000.000 files.
The rest of vector tiles are missing, and when I request a missed one, the header is marked as MISS and is generated on disk.

Comment: I tried to reseed for a smaller area.
In logs I can find:
<br>
2017-05-09 09:53:21,453 INFO [seed.SeedTask] - GWC Seeder Thread-12 completed (re)seeding layer OS:TOPOGRAPHICLINE_CACHE after 1360 tiles and 4 seconds.
2017-05-09 09:53:21,453 INFO [seed.GWCTask] - Thread group finished SEED task after 4.907 seconds
<br>
but on disk, 0 tiles generated.
I get tiles generated If I use the entire extent of the layer, bot less then 10% from the tiles

Answer (score 3):

a team member found the issue.

For geojson tiles seed, you need to set on the layer **Metatiling factors** to 1x1 instead the default 4x4, otherwise GWC will consider that already generated 16 tiles.